# How Can I Return Meaningful Errors In Gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

Let's say I have a huge gremlin query with 100 or more steps. One part of this query has a failure and I want it to return a meaningful error message. With a short and sweet query this would not be too difficult, as we can do something like this:

```
g.V().coalesce(hasId("123"), constant("ERROR - ID does not exist"))
```

Of course we're asking if a Vertex with an ID of 123 exists. If it does not exist we return a string.

So now let's take this example and make it more complex

```
g.V().coalesce(hasId("123"), constant("ERROR - ID does not exist")).as("a").V().coalesce(hasId("123"), constant("ERROR - ID does not exist")).as("b").select("a").valueMap(false)
```

If a vertex with ID: "123" exists we return all properties stored on the vertex.

Lets say a vertex with ID: "123" does not exist in the database. How can I get a meaningful error returned without getting a type error for trying to do a .valueMap() on a string?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, if you have a single line of Gremlin with 100 or more steps (not counting anonymous child traversals steps of course), I'd suggest you re-examine your approach in general. When I encounter Gremlin of that size, it usually means that someone is generating a large traversal for purpose of mutating the graph in some way. That's considered an anti-pattern and something to avoid as the larger the Gremlin grows the greater the chance of hitting the `Xss` JVM limits for a `StackOverflowException` and traversal compilation times tend to add up and get expensive. All of that can be avoided in many cases by using `inject()` or `withSideEffect()` in some way to pass the data in on the traversal itself and then use Gremlin to be the loop that iterates that data into mutation steps. The result is a slightly more complex Gremlin statement, but one that will perform better and avoid the `StackOverflowException`.

Second, note that this traversal will likely not behave as you want on any graph provider - see this example on TinkerGraph:

```
gremlin> g.V().coalesce(hasId(1),constant('x'))
==>v[1]
==>x
==>x
==>x
==>x
==>x
gremlin> g.V().hasId(1)
==>v[1]
```

The `hasId()` inside the `coalesce()` won't be optimized by the graph as an fast `id` lookup but will instead be treated as a full table scan with a filter.

In answer to your question though, I'd say that the easiest option open to you is to just move the `valueMap()` inside the `coalesce()`:

```
g.V().coalesce(hasId("123").valueMap(false), 
               constant("ERROR - ID does not exist")).as("a").
  V().coalesce(hasId("123").valueMap(false), 
               constant("ERROR - ID does not exist")).as("b").
  select("a")
```

I see why that might be bad if you lots of steps other than `valueMap()` because then you have replicate the same steps over and over again making the code even larger. I guess that goes back to my first point.

I suppose you could use a lambda though not all graph providers support that - note that I've modified your code to ensure a lookup by `id` for purpose of demonstration:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).fold().coalesce(unfold(),map{throw new IllegalStateException("bad")})
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.V(10).fold().coalesce(unfold(),map{throw new IllegalStateException("bad")})
bad
```

At this time, I'm not sure there's much else you can do. Maybe you could make a "error" `Vertex` that you could return in `constant()` that way `valueMap()` would work but it's hard to say if that would be helpful given what I know about the overall intent of your traversal. I suppose you could maybe come up with a fancy evaluation of an if-then using `choose()` but that might be hard to read and look awkward. The only other option I can think of is to store the error as a side-effect:

```
gremlin> g.V(10).fold().coalesce(unfold(),store('error').by(constant('x'))).cap('error')
==>[x]
```

I don't think Gremlin gives you any really elegant way to do what you want right now.

**UPDATE:** As of TinkerPop 3.6.x, you may use the `fail()`-step to accomplish this:

```
gremlin> g.V(2).coalesce(out(), fail('no out edges'))
fail() Step Triggered
===============================================================================
Message  > no out edges
Traverser> v[2]
  Bulk   > 1
Traversal> fail("no out edges")
Parent   > CoalesceStep [V((int) 2).coalesce(__.out(),__.fail("no out edges"))]
Metadata > {}
===============================================================================
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your first paragraph talks about gremlin anti-patterns. Do you have any good reading material about these anti-patterns?

Comment: a new section is being added to the Gremlin Recipes documentation as we speak. here's a draft of the work in progress, https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/937a176db7ec0f7c469bd1d5dca01344b956f47d/docs/src/recipes/anti-patterns.asciidoc - will merge in time for publishing with 3.4.0

Comment: @stephenmallette I am also looking for way to return error from gremlin. Is the status still same?

Comment: yes - there is no new method of constructing errors.